# What sensor to use to acquire motion if it is steady constant speed (Android)

Tags: android, motion-detection

What sensor except of location sensors in Android to use to detect the device is in motion if it is steady constant speed without accelerations? The motion detection is sufficient to be of boolean type - just detect if the device moves or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to do it would be location. There are no other sensors to detect steady movement.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My question is more experience centered - I mean will any accelerometer/gravity based sensor be activated in device which is driven in a car driving with steady speed along highway? Is there any such experience acquired by anybody?

Comment: @shevaneshimot Accelerometer/gravity is noisy data - you may want to try the experiment yourself to see how it looks but otherwise Karzmu has the answer.

Comment: I never checked it in the car but I just checked it on my phone and even the smallest move fires the accelerometer sensor. I checked it with: 
using:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en

So it is very likely that you'll notice movement even on the highway because of little bumps on the road. But still you need to check it experimentally, for example with the tool which I linked you :)

Comment: Thanks again. Actually the incentive is to try to make use of some supposedly low power consuming sensor to detect the moments to activate high power consuming location sensor (GRS) to update location only in case it is changed as detected by motion.